# Getting undefined while posting data to node js, from Angular Template

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, again I am trying to post data from Angular js front-end to node js, and then saving it to mongoDb.

**Model**

```
var skuSchema = new Schema({
    merchantId: {type: String, required: false},
    vendorId: {type: String, required: false},
    sku:{
        productId: {type: Array, required: false},
        quantity: {type: Array, required:false}
    }
});
```

**POST method** 
So, I did like this :

```
module.exports.createSku = function (sku, callback) {
    Sku.create(sku, callback);
};
```

**Router**

```
router.post('/add-to-sku', function (req, res, next) {
    var sku= req.body;
    Sku.createSku(sku, function (err, sku) {

        if (err) {
           // res.sendStatus(404);
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(sku);
    });

});
```

But again, I am getting undefined for quantity, & productId. 
What I am doing wrong. 
Please help..

Comment: could you show server side full function code and how you load schema to use in that function ?

Comment: Updated the question with POST & Router code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema should be export as a mongoose model like

```
var skuSchema = new Schema({
    merchantId: {type: String, required: false},
    vendorId: {type: String, required: false},
    sku:{
        productId: [{type: String, required: false}], 
        quantity: [{type: Number, required:false}] 
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Sku', skuSchema );
```

and then load this file in your POST method contained file

In post method file

```
var Sku = require('../your_schema_file_path');


exports.createSku = function (skuData, callback) {
    // check your `skuData` object is it like your schema 
    var newSku = new Sku(skuData);
    newSku.sku.productId = skuData.productId; // if passed {productId:[..]} instead {sku.productId:[..]}
    newSku.save(function(err, sku) {
      if(err) {
         callback(err, null);
      } else {
         callback(null, sku);
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: I have one doubt, When I post data from POSTMAN, then it's saving successfully.But when I post from web-page, I am getting null.Why?

Comment: I am using Angular Js, and when I do console.log, I could see entire data being passed from the angular template, but only while posting to server it's causing problems, why?

Comment: how to call this api from angular can you update your question with angular code?

Comment: `$http({
        url: '/add-to-sku',
        method: "POST",
        data: $scope.sku,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'Application/json'}

      })`

Comment: `$http.post('/add-to-sku', $scope.sku).then(function(success) { console.log("success===",success) }, function(err) { console.log("err==", err);}) ` // check your `$scope.sku` first is sending valid data or not and then check console. which one getting

Comment: tried your code, got success message, but array is empty. 
**Angular console Output :** `data
:
Object
merchantId
:
"1000"
setModel
:
Object
productId
:
Array(0)
quantity
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
__v
:
0
_id
:
"598ff68334e7660fe480a17d"`

Comment: If I do `console.log($scope.sku)` before posting to server, then it's showing, all the data. But if I do `console.log($scope.sku)` while posting to server, then it's showing arrays as empty.

Comment: no you may got valid information just check `console.log("success===",success.data)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151817/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-shaishab-roy).